# change color of 2nd retrieved word in a single row of table

Tags: php

This is my piece of code where i am trying to change the color of the phonetic word. This is retrieved from database. Kindly suggest on how this can be achieved? Below is the screenshot of my obtained output.
I want the word "(anantim)" to be in another color. [image]

```
<?php

   while ($course = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){

   $hindiword=$course['hindiword'];
   $phonetic=$course['phonetic'];
   $id=$course['id'];

       echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td align='center'><font color='#FF00FF'>" 
          .$course['hindiword'] .' (' . $course['phonetic'] .") </td>"; " 
          </tr>" ;  
       echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td align='center'>".$course['hindienglish'] ." </td>"; " 
       </tr>" ;
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='color:#FF00FF;'>".$course['hindiword'] .' ( <span style="color:black;">' . $course['phonetic'] ."</span> ) </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>" ;
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can mark the answer as correct so it can be a reference for future developers.